# how to access which button was pressed in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have made 10 buttons in Flashcard screen of my app and all of them are refering to flashDisplay screen on_press. so in the FlashDisplay screen I need to know which button has been press so that I can fire events accordingly. how can I do that? Is there any property of the button with which gives the index of the button or do we have to use id. and how to do that?

here the part of the kv code-

```
<FlashCard>:
    ScrollView:
        size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 5
            rows: 2
            padding:10
            spacing:10

            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 1'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 2'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 3'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 4'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 5'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 6'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 7'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 8'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 9'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 10'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flash_display'
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
```

py code-

```
class FlashDisplayPage(Screen):      #name of this screen is flash_display

    # code for indexing the button

    # other codes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That property is not by default, so it has to be created. instead of using `root.manager.current = 'flash_display'` you should call another function that passes the index and change the screen. to set the index we can use `setattr` to create a new property, and then we can get that index through `self.index`.

**test.kv**

```
<FlashCard>:
    ScrollView:
        size: self.size
        GridLayout:
            cols: 5
            rows: 2
            padding:10
            spacing:10

            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 1'
                on_press: root.on_press(1)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 2'
                on_press: root.on_press(2)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 3'
                on_press: root.on_press(3)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 4'
                on_press: root.on_press(4)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 5'
                on_press: root.on_press(5)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 6'
                on_press: root.on_press(6)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 7'
                on_press: root.on_press(7)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 8'
                on_press: root.on_press(8)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 9'
                on_press: root.on_press(9)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
            Button:
                text:'Flash Card 10'
                on_press: root.on_press(10)
                width:200
                size_hint_x: None
```

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class FLashCard(Screen):
    def on_press(self, index):
        flash_display_screen = self.manager.get_screen('flash_display')
        setattr(flash_display_screen, 'index', index)
        self.manager.current='flash_display'

class FlashDisplayPage(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        print("on_pre_enter",self.index)

    def on_enter(self):
        print("on_enter", self.index)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(FLashCard(name="flasg_card"))
        sm.add_widget(FlashDisplayPage(name="flash_display"))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot eyllanesc.